# which protocols are used for network device discovery (aka: how to hide a device)

Tags: windows, network-discovery

I've recently setup a new linux server with an ASMB9-iKVM motherboard with IPMI/BMC on our premises.
Everything works great :-)

Today I've discovered that the BMC interface is listed on Windows 11 under the `Network`->`Other devices` (i'm a Linux user by trade, so don't usually have a Win-machine ready, which explains why it took me a while).
What is listed is actually just the name/IP/mac of the device along with the manufacturer (+ homepage), the model (+ modelnumber) and a link to the "device website" (using `http://` even though the device only listens on `https://`, so it's probably just a generic value)

Now I *think* that the system is pretty secure; however, I see no reason to to actually display the management device to all Windows users in my network:

- it is just noise for most
- for the rest it is an invitation to (try to) explore/hack the system

as a result i have tried disabling all network announcing services on the management interface that might be able to announce the device (like `mDNS`) - to no avail.

On my linux box i **do not** see the device, with either of the following:

- BonJour/ZeroConf (using `avahi-discover`)
- SSDP (using `wsdd`)
- uPNP (using `python3 -m netdisco`)

So my question is: how do I find out which service (on the management interface) announces the device for service discovery?
or put otherwise: which service discovery protocols are used by Windows to list ("other") "devices"?
(and how can I discover the same devices on my Linux box, possibly using multiple different tools)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

Comment: https://gary-nebbett.blogspot.com/2021/05/network-discovery-and-name-resolution.html

Comment: The Network in Windows has a long memory. It's not sure that the device is truly still discoverable.

Comment: @harrymc i did reboot the machine multiple times, and it is still there (of course the cache could survive reboots)

Comment: I'm not saying that this is what is happening, but on my computer I can see devices that have not been turned on for days. Again, this is just intended as a note, your problem might be different.